# gathering statistics on tables without indexes

Tags: oracle, indexing, table-statistics

Does it make sense to gather regularly statistics on table without indexes in Oracle database? I'm asking from optimization point of view. I assume that always FULL TABLE SCAN would be performed on that table.

Comment: If you're using Oracle 11g or greater then Oracle will automatically gather statistics for you...

Comment: There is lot of information out there on the web, so I thought of explaining it with an example. See my answer.

Comment: Even if there is no other options than to use full table scan it's worth of it. Imagine you join this table with other table and you filer the result. Optimizer can either choose nested loop, or hash join. But hash join is more effective iff the whole hash table fits into RAM. And here stats. might help estimate the size of hash table.

Comment: @Ben, I see. You are talking about **auto optimizer stats collection**. Do you use it on your production system? I don't think so.

Comment: It shouldn't be something you rely upon as the sole method of ensuring that your stats are up-to-date @lalit, but why would you _not_ use automatic stats collection?

Comment: Since I know about my application needs more than any automatic functionality. Nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's still worth gathering the statistics. Information about the number and size of rows is of use to the optimizer, even though there are no indexes

Comment: In addition to what @Dave has said, other information is also collected such as number of distinct values (NDV), skewness of data (if histograms are being collected) and high/low values. Every little bit of help you can give the optimizer is not wasted!

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, **statistics** are as important to **optimizer** as food is to human beings. If you don't get to eat for a long time, your brain would degrade in its functioning.

The more the optimizer knows the latest statistics, the better is the execution plan it could decide.

Let me try to explain with an example:

Let's say you are asked to reach a particular destination on a fine day. However, you are not provided with the map and location information. Now, there could be N number of ways to reach the destination, but without proper information you would make the worst possible way. If you are smart enough, you might ask for directions, now this is where you start **gathering statistics**. Just imagine, if you had the entire plan in mind before you start your journey, i.e. if you could gather all the statistics, you could make the best plan.

**UPDATE** Saw a comment about **auto optimizer stats collection**.

Yes, Of course there is **auto optimizer stats collection** in `Oracle 11g Release 1`. Please see more information [here](http://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/automated-database-maintenance-task-management-11gr1.php)